# Is "would play" correct?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, would

> We had a small house with a large garden, and we would play in a garden for hours.

Is it correct to say "would play" in this context?

Comment: Please can you add details about why you think it is or is not correct?

Comment: Did you play in _the_ garden associated with the house or did you play in _a_ garden. _A garden_ can mean one of a number of available gardens, possibly including the one associated with your house. Your use of "would" indicates that the playing was habitual so playing "in a garden" could mean that, over time, you played in a number of different gardens. In the context you give _the garden_ refers only to the one already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the word is used appropriately. The sentence should be- (errors are italicized)

> We had a small house with a large garden, and we would play in *the*
>   garden for hours.